# android app side menu like google map menu

Tags: android-layout

I am looking to put side menu similar to "google map" side menu which appears next to "Search Google Maps" you click on the icon and you get menu
is there any framework to implement ?

spending much time but can't find out how

can any expert advise/suggest/help me 
I would appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is navigation menu with `layout_gravity="start"`.
Declare your layout like as shown below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
//put your menu items here...
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If u want to see the hamburger icon as well then use the code below:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,  drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

and override onPostCreate as:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

Let me know if this is not enough for you...

Comment: I am using Android studio. I am trying to use "Widgets" in android studio to "drawer layout" .But I can't find "drawer layout" in android studio.

Comment: Add the the line `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` to ur app Module in gradle script.

Comment: are you saying that I just copy and past layout code and use the compile in the gradle build script. because I am using android studio, I can't see a layout/widget called "DrawerLayout" is it due to latest version of android studio that I am using

Comment: Yes. just take care of the compile sdk version and build tools version.

Comment: No. It is because Drawer Layout is available in the support library. So u have to add the dependency in ur gradle script. see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for more details.

Comment: i am able to build the app now. when i copy the apt file to android mobile phone and try to install, i am getting error on the phone that " the application test has stopped unexpectedly please try again. i have built with sdk version 2.3.3 which is what my phone is using